# Scaling an image up in Corona SDK without it becoming fuzzy

Tags: graphics, coronasdk, scaling

I am working on a classic RPG that requires a pixelated style of graphics.  I want to do this by making a small image and scaling it up.  However, when I do this, it gets fuzzy.  Is there any way to scale it while keeping a crisp edge for every pixel, or do I just need to make a bigger image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot scale an image expecting it to keep a crisp aspect if it's not made in a big enough resolution in the first place. In your case you would have to make a bigger image and scale it down to make the small image.
If you do not use the large image all the time however, you should consider having two versions of the same image (one small / one large) for optimization sake.